Why is $\phi[\top / q] \vee \phi[\perp / q] \equiv \phi$?
I'm pretty confused by the use of this equivalence in the induction proof for the Craig's Interpolation Theorem. In the equation, $\phi$ is a formula, and $q$ is an atomic formula in $\phi$, with $\phi[\top / q]$ denoting the formula $\phi$ with every instance of $q$ replaced by $\top$, which according to my consultation, means a statement that is always true. The same meaning for $\phi[\perp / q]$, which means the formula $\phi$ with every instance of $q$ replaced by $\perp$, which is supposed to be a statement that is always false.
However, I don't really see why this equation hold. Well, $q$ just seems to disappear in $\phi[\top / q] \vee \phi[\perp / q]$. How can this be equivalent to $\phi$, then?
Any insightful answer or hint would be appreciated.

What is $\psi$?

Oh, sorry, that was a typo. It's corrected now.

In the proof you linked, it is not suggested that this is a equivalence, only a semantic consequence: $\phi\vDash \phi[\top/q]\lor \phi[\bot/q]$.

Yes, it’s not an equivalence in that proof. But the equivalence is actually true. Still, I know neither how to prove the equivalence nor the semantic consequence.

It seems to be a quite straightforward conclusion, judging from the briefness of its statement in many proofs. It’s just that at the moment I don’t find it so obvious to be true.

The equivalence seems false. Indeed, consider $\phi = q$, with $q$ an atomic formula.
Then $\phi[\top/q]\lor \phi[\bot/q] = \top\lor \bot \equiv \top$, but $\phi=q\not\equiv \top$.
However, the semantic consequence $\phi \vDash \phi[\top/q]\lor \phi[\bot/q]$ holds.
Indeed, consider $\mu$ a truth assignment that satisfies $\phi$. There are two cases:

either $\mu(q) = 1$, therefore $\mu(\phi) = \mu(\phi[\top/q]) = 1$;
or $\mu(q) = 0$, therefore $\mu(\phi) = \mu(\phi[\bot/q]) = 1$

In both case, $\mu$ satisfies $\phi[\top/q]\lor \phi[\bot/q]$.

Oh yeah, it seems I made a mistake about equivalence. The rest is quite clear, thanks a lot!  But now I do have another guess at the equivalence: is the equivalence true as long as $q$ is strictly contained in $\phi$? i.e., it is a sub formula but isn’t exactly the formula.

@The_Eureka no, because you could have $\phi = q\lor q$, or $\phi = q\lor \psi$, with $\psi$ being a tautology, and it would still not be an equivalence.

Alright, got it, thanks!

Recall the definition of $\equiv$; $P \equiv Q$ means that both formulas $P$ and $Q$ evaluate to same (true or false) for any fixed assignments of the variables.
In your case, the sub-formula $q$ can either be true or false, thus the formula $\phi$ is true if and only if at least one of $\phi[\top/q]$ or $\phi[\bot/q]$ is true.
